# Php mosquitto mqtt client identify client onDisconnect

Tags: php, callback, mqtt, mosquitto, phpmqtt

I am working on PHP project using [mosquitto client](http://mosquitto-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html), I need to check when some user disconnects, and identify the user.

I am using code callback function which only contains the reason for disconnect.

```
onDisconnect($callback)
```

function so that I can handle the disconnect event.

How to link the event to the user in the database.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That callback is saying that **your client** was disconnected, not some other client (which is what you mean by "user" probably). You can know that another client disconnected only if

- that client has set Last Will topic and disconnected abruptly - this will be published by the broker for you
- that client will publish a specific graceful disconnection topic - you must provide the publishing

In both cases, **your client** must be subscribed to the topic in question, of course.

Comment: but, I still don't know which client disconnected !!

Comment: @MostafaKhattab **your client**. You. The PHP script which called `connect()`

Comment: I mean other clients, who connect on the same server and publish on topics shared with php client script. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: MQTT broker (what you call "server") does not inform about every client about disconnection of every other client. You must do one of the things in the answer.